# Change field required dynamically base on user select in Symfony 4 Form

Tags: forms, symfony

i need my app require(true/false) a title(TextType) based on what select from 'event' field(ChoiceType) in a single form.

So, how can i modify my 'title' base on what user select on 'event' dynamically?

Comment: Form events dude. Or custom form constraint.

Answer (score 0):

How to dynamically Generate Forms Based on user Data

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#how-to-dynamically-generate-forms-based-on-user-data

Add the EventListener on your ChoiceType.